# Getting stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder627278946/package.json: no such file or directory while building the image on gitlab

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

The files which i am using are as below:
gitlab-ci.yaml file below

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
docker-build-master:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:18-git
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:18-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - echo "Deploying Frontend..."
    - docker build --file=angular/Dockerfile --rm=true -t "$CI_REGISTRY_REPO/$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_REPO/$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - echo "Frontend Deployment Complete!"
  only:
    - master
```

I have my front end docker file which needs to be build is as follows

```
FROM node:12.18.1 as build

# install chrome for protractor tests
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq google-chrome-stable

# Install necesaay tools which may be needed
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install nano
RUN apt-get -y install htop
RUN apt-get -y install net-tools


# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . /app

##To Test If all files are in place..
#RUN ng --version
#RUN ls -a


# run tests
#RUN ng test --watch=false
#RUN ng e2e --port 4202

# generate build
RUN ng build --prod --output-path=dist

############
### prod ###
############

# base image
FROM nginx:1.17

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /app/dist /var/www/html

# Add
# RUN groupadd -r www-data &&\
#     useradd -r -g www-data www-data

# ensure www-data user exists
# RUN set -x ; \
#   addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
#   adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN rm -r /var/www/html/assets/data/config/appConfig.json

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The error which i am getting is

```
Step 12/24 : COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder627278946/package.json: no such file or directory
```

when i check on my system there is no docker-builder627... folder inside tmp folder.
Can anyone put forward his/her thoughts on that?
Thanks

Comment: That error message says the `package.json` file isn't in the directory you passed as the last option to `docker build` (but with a confusing directory name).

Comment: @DavidMaze the problem is in source file or directory?

Comment: even if i do RUN $(pwd) it shows image layer i guess

Comment: Done now Thanks @DavidMaze